# VBA - Event inside event (BeforeClose -> BeforeSave) not working

Tags: excel, vba, events

I've hijacked saving in an excel file for the purposes of preventing unintended overwrites of a file in an odd environment.

The Workbook_BeforeSave and the Workbook_BeforeClose events work perfectly on their own. Unfortunately, the way the code is currently structured, I would need to call the BeforeSave event from within the BeforeClose event.

In the most basic form, the following code will not do as I'd like. In the following example, wksHiddenWorksheet.Visible = True will not make wksHiddenWorksheet visible if the save is called from within the BeforeClose event.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    wksHiddenWorksheet.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Is there any way around this? Is it poor practise (or even fundamentally incorrect) to call an event from inside another event in the way that I'm attempting?

Update:

I have played around with Application.EnableEvents in the workbook, but I've made sure it always reverts back to True in error handling.

I've opened a brand new workbook and entered the following code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Debug.Print Application.EnableEvents 'Prints TRUE    
    ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    'The workbook consists of two sheets. Sheet1 and Sheet2
    Sheet1.Visible = xlSheetHidden

    Debug.Print Sheet1.Visible 'Prints -1 (xlSheetVisible)

End Sub
```

The Visible sheet does not become hidden, though the line is triggered if I go line by line through the code. If I enter code such as a MsgBox in the same space, the MsgBox will open as normal.

Update 2:

To answer everyone's questions and display exactly what happens, please see the below code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    'The workbook consists of two sheets. Sheet1 and Sheet2
    Debug.Print Application.EnableEvents 'Prints TRUE
    Debug.Print Sheet1.Visible 'Prints -1 (xlSheetVisible)

    Sheet1.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    Sheet1.Visible = False 'Same thing

    Debug.Print Sheet1.Visible 'Prints 0 (xlSheetHidden)

    Sheet1.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheet1.Visible = True 'Same thing

    Debug.Print Sheet1.Visible 'Prints -1 (xlSheetVisible)

    ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)


    Debug.Print Sheet1.Visible 'Prints -1 (xlSheetVisible)

    Sheet1.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    Sheet1.Visible = False 'Same thing

    'Sheet1 should now be hidden, but it's not
    Debug.Print Sheet1.Visible 'Prints -1 (xlSheetVisible)

End Sub
```

Hiding and unhiding sheets works perfectly in the first event, but as soon as the second event is triggered, the sheet visibility does not change.

Update 3:

Another point. If I enter the Workbook_BeforeSave() event directly (by saving), rather than entering it from the Workbook_BeforeClose() event, then everything works as expected.

MUCH LATER UPDATE:

Although I marked this question as solved a while ago, I've come across an article that helps to explain the behaviour. An explanation can be found at:
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/events.aspx

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem, it works just fine for me. Is this all the code or do you have some more code there?

Comment: Why not put the code of the BeforeSave inside a sub, and just call that sub inside BeforeClose? Is that what you are after?

Comment: @RyanWildry: I suspect that event handling is disabled. so that would not fix the issue. otherwise we lack crucial informations form Alexander. Let's wait for his feedback

Comment: So if I attempt to close the sheet, all of the code in the BeforeClose event works as it should. If I call a sub from within it, it works perfectly. However, after the code goes to ThisWorkbook.Save and enters the BeforeSave event, the same sub that was in the BeforeClose will not work properly. No error arises.

Comment: I've explicitly enabled event handling as well

Comment: the explicit event handler enabling must be done in a code that is executed before any possible user closing or saving commands. doing it in the event handlers themselves wouldn't have any effect

Comment: haha yes I noticed that right after I submitted the response. My mistake. I've modified my update. In any case, the Debug.Print Application.EnableEvents  Prints TRUE and every line is triggered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edited** after all clarifications

the following code worked for me

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Workbook_BeforeSave False, True
    ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Cancel Then Sheet1.Visible = xlSheetHidden

End Sub
```

hard to tell why though...

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've made sure that Application.EnableEvents = True and the events do fire. Unfortunately, this is not the problem.

Comment: have you stepped through code? to ensure that events handler get actually triggered

Comment: Yes I've stepped line by line through the code. Every line gets triggered.

Comment: So at user closing command you actually enter `Workbook_BeforeClose()` event handler and hit `ThisWorkbook.Save` statement and that does not  trigger (e.g.: you don't enter) `Workbook_BeforeSave()` event?

Comment: I enter the Workbook_BeforeClose() event handler, then I hit the ThisWorkbook.Save statement, and then I do enter the Workbook_BeforeSave() event. All lines in the Workbook_BeforeSave() event trigger. No errors are triggered. The above example shows sheet visibilities not behaving as expected even though they are triggered in the Workbook_BeforeSave() event.

Comment: Using `Workbook_BeforeSave False, True` worked! I'm also not exactly sure why this would work and entering the event through `ThisWorkbook.Save` would not, but you've solved the issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: you are welcome. it's been a tough but interesting issue, indeed!

Answer (score 1):

In this example procedure `HideSheet` is called from `BeforeSave` and from `BeforeClose` event handler. So both handlers hide the sheet. HTH

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    HideSheet Sheet1
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    HideSheet Sheet1
End Sub

Private Sub HideSheet(wks As Worksheet)
    wks.Visible = xlSheetHidden
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. xlSheetHidden should be the same as False here. In any case, I added this command to my Update 2. This unfortunately does not solve the issue